# Edit Gnome GTK2 & GTK3 settings systemwide to change default white background color

Tags: gnome, gedit, desktop-background

I need to change the #FFFFFF white background color to #808080 system-wide on all Gnome gtk2 and gtk3 apps windows on Lubuntu 18.04 LTS. Apps such as Firefox, Gnome Disks, Gnome Software and many others do not obey theme color change, so I need to edit Gnome-shell and/or Ubuntu-shell files in terminal as a root using gedit. Does anyone knows the correct command line syntax to do that? I have been searching for the answer everywhere with no success. Please help. Thank you.